# how do I rewrite the myFunction so it works

Tags: javascript, reduce

How do I get this:

```
console.log(items.reduce(myFunction))
```

to produce the same answer as:

```
console.log(items.reduce((max, {price}) => price > max ? price : max, 0))
```

```js
let items = [
    {
      itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
      type: "book",
      price: 13.99
    },
    {
      itemName: "Creation 3005",
      type: "computer",
      price: 299.99
    },
    {
      itemName: "Finding Your Center",
      type: "book",
      price: 15.00
    }
  ]
  
  

console.log(items.reduce((max, {price}) => price > max ? price : max, 0))



function myFunction(max, {price}){

if(price > max ){

 
return price
 
}

}

console.log(items.reduce(myFunction))
```

Comment: What if `price <= max`?

Comment: doesn't matter in this case

Comment: Sure? Because that's an obvious difference between the arrow function and vanilla function implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no second argument is passed to `reduce` the first element of the array will be used as the initial value of the accumulator(which is bad in your case as each element is an object);

Also, when `price > max` is false, you're not returning anything so accumulator will be set to `undefined`.

```js
let items = [{
    itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 13.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Creation 3005",
    type: "computer",
    price: 299.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Finding Your Center",
    type: "book",
    price: 15.00
  }
]



console.log(items.reduce((max, {
  price
}) => price > max ? price : max, 0))



function myFunction(max, {
  price
}) {
  if (price > max) {
    return price
  }
  return max
}

console.log(items.reduce(myFunction, 0))
```

Comment: In this statement items.reduce(myFunction, 0) with this statement function myFunction(max, {
  price
}) -> 0 becomes the accumulator max, then the return statements become the new value of the accumulaor?

Comment: @DCR Yeah, whatever is returned in the callback passed as the first argument to reduce will be assigned to the accumulator in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You need a small start value and return `max` in the function, if `price` is not greater.

```js
function myFunction(max, { price }) {
  if (price > max) {
    return price;
  }
  return max;
}

let items = [{ itemName: "Effective Programming Habits", type: "book", price: 13.99 }, { itemName: "Creation 3005", type: "computer", price: 299.99 }, { itemName: "Finding Your Center", type: "book", price: 15.00 }]

console.log(items.reduce((max, { price }) => price > max ? price : max, 0))

console.log(items.reduce(myFunction, -Number.MAX_VALUE));
```